# What is the equivalent of "size_t" in C?

Tags: c, arrays, memory

Suppose I want to make a function like

```
int indexOf ( char * str, char c )
{
   // returns the index of the chracter c in the string str 
   // returns -1 if c is not a character of str
  int k = 0;  
  while (*str)
  { 
      if (*str == c) break;
      else ++str;
  }
  return *str ? k : -1;  
}
```

but I want to make it as reliable as possible. For instance, the above only works if the largest `int` is guaranteed to be greater than or equal to the maximum size of a character array. How can I cover all my bases in pure C?

Comment: [Why reinvent the wheel?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr)

Comment: size_t is present in C99 standard, what do you mean by saying "pure C"?

Comment: Were you supposed to be incrementing `k` inside that loop?

Comment: What exactly means "For instance, the above only works if the largest int is guaranteed to be greater than or equal to the maximum size of a character array"?  I'm trying to understand the question.

Comment: @Hurkyl Whoops! Haha. Now you probably understand where my username came from.

Comment: @Shondeslitch he means if `INT_MAX>=strlen(str)`

Comment: @myaut `size_t` has been around since at least C89.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t)

No, seriously. `size_t` is a standard C type. It's defined in `<stddef.h>`.

(that was the answer to *"What is the equivalent of “size_t” in C?"*)

For the exact function like you wrote, `strchr` would be more suitable - the caller could use it like this:

```
const char* str = "Find me!find mE";
char* pos = strchr(str, '!');
if(pos) // found the char
{
    size_t index = (pos - str); // get the index
    // do the other things
}
else
{
    // char not found
}
```

So, in general, if you want to find something in the array provided by user, returning a pointer is most idiomatic in C.

You *could* return `ssize_t` (which includes all the possible values of `size_t`, and `-1`), but it's not standard C, so I don't recommend it. I only mention it for completeness.

Comment: I think OP would be curious of how to deal with `return -1` part of his code.

Comment: OP is aware of size_t existing. However your answer doesn't show how to return a -1 or equivalent.

Comment: @2501 I think that the question only need how to know if the char is in the string and the index. If the return is different to -1, while you know which is the return that confirm what you want is ok. (However, you are correct)

Answer (score 4):

Use a pointer.

You will always be able to return a pointer to a valid element in an array. The not-found condition is signaled by returning a NULL.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the proper way of doing `strchr` in C, no questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting your question as:

`How to not rely in index size for pointer arithmetic?`

The answer would be:

```
int indexOf ( char * str, char c )
{
    // returns the index of the chracter c in the string str 
    // returns -1 if c is not a character of str
    char *aux = str;  
    while (*aux != c )
    { 
        if (*aux == '\0')
            return -1;
        aux++;
    }
    return aux - str; 
}
```

Comment: The division is wrong anyway, if it was for another type. `ptr + 1` points at the next element, not at the next byte.

Comment: You are right, I though the operation between two pointers would ignore the type size.